# How to check when srcset images have been loaded when appending them via Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, image, callback, srcset

I'm appending the text and images of a php-page via Ajax to a container and showing it after all the images have been loaded. This works perfectly If I'm using only src, but not if I'm using srcset.

So far, I'm using this snippet of code, to check if all the ajaxed src-tagged images have been loaded. But of course, it's not actually working because it's checking the src and not the srcset.

```
$.fn.imagesLoaded = function () {
    var $imgs = this.find('img[src!=""]');

    if (!$imgs.length) {
        return $.Deferred().resolve().promise();
    }

    var dfds = [];  

    $imgs.each(function(){
        var dfd = $.Deferred();
        dfds.push(dfd);

        var img = new Image();

        img.onload = function(){
            dfd.resolve();
        }

        img.onerror = function(){
            dfd.resolve();
        }

        img.src = this.src;

    });

    return $.when.apply($,dfds);
}
```

This is my Ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    url: "somefile.php",
    success: function(data) {
        $("body").prepend(data).imagesLoaded().then(function(){
           // show the images etc.
        })
)}
```

The expected result should be, that the checking if all images have been loaded should also work with srcset not only with src. The actual result is, that it's just not respecting the imagesLoaded().

Comment: It's not as elegant as adding an event listener, but I guess you **could** user setInterval() and exit when the conditions are met?

Comment: Unfortunately, – using Ajax – I don't know how to check wether srcset images are loaded or not. :/